# Python: How to append file content into format string?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am trying to insert the file content of an multi-line SQL file within a Python script:

```python
sql_file = open(sql_file_path, 'r')
file_content = sql_file.read()
file_content = file_content.replace("placeholder", "realvalue")

import_cmd = 'ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" \
-lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom \
PG:"host=localhost user={db_user_name} port=5432 \
dbname={db_name} password={db_password}" \
{source_file} -nln "{db_table_name}" \
-sql "$(cat {file_content})"'

os.system(import_cmd.format(
  db_user_name=db_user_name,
  db_name=db_name,
  db_password=db_password,
  source_file=source_file,
  db_table_name=db_table_name,
  file_content=file_content
))
```

The file `sql_file_path` contains multiple lines. The content is modified via `replace`. Then th new `file_content` has to be appended to the `-sql` parameter of the `ogr2ogr` command line tool. However, the script throws this error:

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Comment: did you really want to `"$(cat {file_content})"` and not `echo`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `os.system`. Use [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) and pass in your arguments as a list:

```
import subprocess

conn_info = (
    'PG:host=localhost user={db_user_name} port=5432 '
    'dbname={db_name} password={db_password}'.format(
        db_user_name=db_user_name,
        db_name=db_name,
        db_password=db_password))

subprocess.call([
    'ogr2ogr', '-f', 'PostgreSQL', '-lco', 'GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom',
    conn_info, source_file, '-nln', db_table_name, '-sql', file_content])
```

This won't go through a shell but invokes the program directly, and each argument passed in directly as is. No further quoting required.

Comment: The process fails with `: File name too long` when I pass the multi-line `file_content`.

Comment: @JJD: are you certain that the order of arguments works for the tool? The [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) is a little cryptic, but perhaps the `-sql` parameter has to come before the the `dst_datasource_name` and `src_datasource_name` arguments. What does a working command line (with quotes) look like?